# how to read values from cloudant database using python

Tags: python, cloudant

can any one tell me the correct way to extract data from cloudant database using python? I used [this](https://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html) documentation and try to retrieve data but it always give empty documents.I am using cloudant==2.14.0

I have sample database like below.

```
{
 "id": "0726fa413b4ccf1e7ea549b40c55efd3",
 "key": "0726fa413b4ccf1e7ea549b40c55efd3",
 "value": {
  "rev": "77-71ebe0b54e30ed6ef27d7c79b3280c6a"
 },
 "doc": {
  "_id": "0726fa413b4ccf1e7ea549b40c55efd3",
  "_rev": "77-71ebe0b54e30ed6ef27d7c79b3280c6a",
  "clientName": "client1",
  "projectName": "project33"
}}
```

I tried to extract values as below

```
client = Cloudant.iam("CLOUDANT_ACCOUNT", "CLOUDANT_KEY",connect=True)
db = client['project'] 
print(db.exists()) #this line gives true
query = Query(db, selector={'clientName': 'client1'})
for doc in query(limit=100, skip=100)['docs']:
  print(doc) #empty
```

```
client = Cloudant.iam("CLOUDANT_ACCOUNT", "CLOUDANT_KEY",connect=True)
db = CloudantDatabase(client,'project', fetch_limit=100, partitioned=False)
print(db.exists()) #this line gives true
query = Query(db, selector={'clientName': 'client1'})
for doc in my_database.view('_all_docs'):
  print(doc) #empty
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: it gives empty results from the way i extracted. can you please tell me the correct way to extract data.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. Have you done any debugging?